# Having UDT in Cassandra can cause performance issue?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Having UDT in Cassandra can cause performance issue? Is it anti-pattern? Should we normalise table to use separate table for UDT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no, no. UDTs just serialize it on C* side vs on client side. If you really want you can just set the field type to blob and serialize it on app side.

Comment: Agree with you, as per my understanding Cassandra serializes UDT while storing. This is a good design option.